# How the values of kernel parameters are defined?

Tags: linux-kernel

I am trying to install Oracle 11g on Oracle Linux 7.6 machine. So as part pre-requisites check, how the values for Kernel parameters are defined. Because I can see unexpected values for max seg size.

On what basis the values will be assigned to those parameters.

```
max seg size (kbytes) = 18014398509465599
max total shared memory (kbytes) = 18014398442373116
```

My laptop RAM size is 8GB.

Please help me on this.

Thanks,
Chy

```
[chy@myserver ~]$ ipcs -l

------ Messages Limits --------
max queues system wide = 32000
max size of message (bytes) = 8192
default max size of queue (bytes) = 16384

------ Shared Memory Limits --------
max number of segments = 4096
max seg size (kbytes) = 18014398509465599
max total shared memory (kbytes) = 18014398442373116
min seg size (bytes) = 1

------ Semaphore Limits --------
max number of arrays = 32000
max semaphores per array = 32000
max semaphores system wide = 1024000000
max ops per semop call = 500
semaphore max value = 32767
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The numbers in the output of `ipcs -l` you see are the default (unchanged) values of these parameters, which are hard-coded in the kernel itself.

When the kernel [creates the IPC namespace](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/b5c8314f0ebadb6d8a9789cb2d646cbef8448073/ipc/namespace.c#L32) (these parameters are defined per namespace), it [initializes it](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/ipc/namespace.c#L55) and [sets the limits to defaults](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/b5c8314f0ebadb6d8a9789cb2d646cbef8448073/ipc/shm.c#L101), which are defined [here](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/b5c8314f0ebadb6d8a9789cb2d646cbef8448073/include/uapi/linux/shm.h#L12-L25) as follows:

```c
#define SHMMIN 1                         /* min shared seg size (bytes) */
#define SHMMNI 4096                      /* max num of segs system wide */
#define SHMMAX (ULONG_MAX - (1UL << 24)) /* max shared seg size (bytes) */
#define SHMALL (ULONG_MAX - (1UL << 24)) /* max shm system wide (pages) */
#define SHMSEG SHMMNI                    /* max shared segs per process */
```

As you see, these defaults do not depend on the actual size of your RAM. As to the default value of maximum shared segment size, [SHMMAX](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/b5c8314f0ebadb6d8a9789cb2d646cbef8448073/include/uapi/linux/shm.h#L23) - it is defined as `ULONG_MAX - (1UL << 24)` (i.e. depends only on maximum size of `unsigned long`), which after evaluation (on x86_64 box) gives `18446744073692774399` in bytes, i.e. `18014398509465599` in kilobytes, and that is exactly the number you see in `max seg size (kbytes)` line of `ipcs -l` output.

You should not be confused by the fact that this value is greater than your **physical** RAM size - it all is about the **virtual** memory, which is much larger than the physical RAM.

Comment: So how to calculate and set these values for installation of Oracle 11g database? what will happen if I proceed installation without changing these values?

Comment: @chy sorry, but I'm not an expert in Oracle DB, and the answer depends on how it uses the shared memory, i.e. this question is Oracle-specific rather than Linux-specific (and can not be expected to be answered under the single `[linux-kernel]` tag). Probably you have to consult the Oracle documentation or ask another question under `[oracle11g]` tag (or search for existing ones).